# How to give Laravel 6 validation attributes a custom name for error message?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation, laravel-6

I am trying to change the way my errors display when my Laravel form is not filled in correctly. Currently, when I get an error. It displays like this.

> name mag niet groter zijn dan 255 karakters.

Because this language is Dutch, I would like to change the **'name'** attribute to **'naam'**. I have tried to change the `$attributesNames` like this but unfortunately it did not work.

```
$attributeNames = [
   'name' => 'Naam'   
];
```

This is what my validation function currently looks like.

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function validateCampaign() {
    // name needs to render as 'Naam'

    return request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out. I needed to edit the `'attributes'` array in my `resources/lang/xx/validation.php` file.

It turns out like this:

```
'attributes' => [
    'name' => 'Naam'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining previous examples, you could do this...

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function validateCampaign() {
    // name needs to render as 'Naam'

    return request()->validate(
        ['name' => 'required|max:255'],  // rules
        [],                              // messages
        ['name' => 'Naam']               // custom attributes
    );
}
```

The Laravel 6 implementation details of the `validate` function can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.php#L134).

Answer (score 0):

hey i found similar issue like you maybe [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187846/how-to-give-custom-field-name-in-laravel-form-validation-error-message)

maybe like this

```
    $attributeNames = array(
        'name' => 'Naam',  
    );

    $validator = Validator::make ( request()->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
    $validator->setAttributeNames($attributeNames);
```

and you can see more about this in [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-error-messages)

Comment: This is not really a clean way of doing this.This because I would like to keep my code as simple as possible.

Comment: sure,i just share what i found

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to set up custom error message:

```
public function validateCampaign() {
    // name needs to render as 'Naam'

    return request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ],[
        'name.required' => 'Namm is required',
        'name.max' => 'Namm must be max 255 length'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What I was looking for was only changing the attribute name, not the whole error message.

Comment: I know it is much more than you need but maybe some people in future will need to change entire message as well.